How to finetune open-clip
I have sucessfully tried to use the ViT-L-14 with open-clip without changing anything of its structure. Now I want to adapt it a little bit to the CIFAR100 database and to do so i have defined a ProjectionHead class, which takes the encoded image features and projects them into a projection dimension and then it does the same for the text encoder.
Everything works until I reach the loss.backward() as the following runtime error appears:

loss.backward()
torch.autograd.backward(
Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

I have to say that I have already said that i do not want to change the parameters of the VIT-L-14 but of the image projection class:
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
    
    for param in image_projection.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True

    for param in text_projection.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True

The complete code is the following, i hope it is clear enough.
I would really appreciate your help as i have been working non stopping and i am kind of stuck as i am kind of new to DL.
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR100
import open_clip
import torch.nn.functional as F
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split, Dataset
from torchvision import transforms
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import wandb
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import CosineAnnealingLR


def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
        pred = output.topk(max(topk), 1, True, True)[1].t()
        correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))
        return [float(correct[:k].reshape(-1).float().sum(0, keepdim=True).cpu().numpy()) for k in topk]

class CIFAR100WithExtraColumn(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, cifar_dataset,classes):
        self.cifar_dataset = cifar_dataset
        self.classes = classes

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cifar_dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = {}
        image, target = self.cifar_dataset[index]
        classname = self.classes[target]
        classname_with_prefix = "a photo of " + classname
        text = open_clip.tokenize(classname_with_prefix)
        
        item['image'] = image
        item['target'] = text
        
        return item

class CIFAR100DataModule(LightningModule): #saved as binary files
    def __init__(
        self,
        data_dir: str = './',
        train_batch_size: int = 100,
        val_batch_size: int = 100,
        num_workers: int = 11,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.train_batch_size = train_batch_size
        self.val_batch_size = val_batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        # Define transforms
        self.train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert PIL Image to tensor
        ])
        self.val_transforms = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert PIL Image to tensor
        ])
        # Load CIFAR100 data to get class names
        cifar100_temp = CIFAR100(self.data_dir, train=True, download=True)
        self.cifar_classes = list(cifar100_temp.class_to_idx.keys())  
    def prepare_data(self):
        # Download the data
        CIFAR100(self.data_dir, train=True, download=True)
        CIFAR100(self.data_dir, train=False, download=True)

    def setup(self, preprocess, stage=None):
        # Assign train/val datasets for use in dataloaders
        if stage == 'fit' or stage is None:
            cifar_full = CIFAR100(self.data_dir, train=True, transform=preprocess)
            self.cifar_train, self.cifar_val = random_split(cifar_full, [45000, 5000])

        # Assign test dataset for use in dataloader(s)
        if stage == 'test' or stage is None:
            self.cifar_test = CIFAR100(self.data_dir, train=False, transform=preprocess)
        
        # Adding labels to train and val datasets
        if stage == 'fit' or stage == 'test' or stage is None:
            self.cifar_train = CIFAR100WithExtraColumn(self.cifar_train,cifar_full.classes)
            self.cifar_val = CIFAR100WithExtraColumn(self.cifar_val,cifar_full.classes)
            self.cifar_test = CIFAR100WithExtraColumn(self.cifar_test,cifar_full.classes)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.cifar_train, batch_size=self.train_batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers, persistent_workers=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.cifar_val, batch_size=self.val_batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers, persistent_workers=True)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.cifar_test, batch_size=self.val_batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers, persistent_workers=True)


text_embedding = 768 #output to vision encoder => print(text_features.shape)
image_embedding = 768
num_epochs = 100
# ross_entropy function is a custom implementation that expects preds to be raw, unnormalized scores (logits) and targets to be one-hot encoded labels. 
# This is different from PyTorch's built-in nn.CrossEntropyLoss, which expects targets to be class indices
def cross_entropy(preds, targets, reduction='none'):
    log_softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=-1)
    loss = (-targets * log_softmax(preds)).sum(1)
    if reduction == "none":
        return loss
    elif reduction == "mean":
        return loss.mean()

class ProjectionHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        embedding_dim,
        projection_dim=256,
        dropout=0.4
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.projection = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, projection_dim)
        self.gelu = nn.GELU()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(projection_dim, projection_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(projection_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        projected = self.projection(x)
        x = self.gelu(projected)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = x + projected
        x = self.layer_norm(x)
        return x
    
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"  
    
    
    image_projection = ProjectionHead(embedding_dim=image_embedding).to(device)
    text_projection = ProjectionHead(embedding_dim=text_embedding).to(device)


    # Load the model
    model, preprocess,_ = open_clip.create_model_and_transforms('ViT-L-14', 'datacomp_xl_s13b_b90k')

    # Download the dataset
    data_module = CIFAR100DataModule(train_batch_size=254, val_batch_size=254, num_workers=11)    


    # Prepare the inputs
    data_module.setup(preprocess)
    train_dataloader = data_module.train_dataloader()
    val_dataloader = data_module.val_dataloader()
    test_dataloader = data_module.test_dataloader()

    model.cuda()
    
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
    
    for param in image_projection.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True

    for param in text_projection.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(list(image_projection.parameters()) + list(text_projection.parameters()), lr=0.0001)
    # Define the scheduler
    scheduler = CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=10)
    
    #print the shape of train_dataloader
    #print("Train Dataloader")
    # first_batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
    # print(type(first_batch)) 

    run_name = "ViT-L14-CIFAR100"

    
    #wandb.init(project='finetuning',name=run_name)

    # Calculate features
    with torch.no_grad():
        patience = 5
        increasing_val_loss_counter = 0
        best_val_loss = float('inf')
        train_losses = []
        val_losses = []
        top1_train, total_loss, n_train,top5_train = 0., 0., 0.,0.
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for i, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
                images = batch['image'].cuda()
                text = batch['target']
    
                if isinstance(text, str):
                    text = torch.tensor(text).cuda()
                else:
                    text = text.cuda() #to cuda only tensors
                                    
                # Zero the gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                image_features = model.encode_image(images)
                #print(image_features.shape)
                #print(target.shape)
                text = text.squeeze(1)  # Remove the extra dimension
                #print(target.shape)
                text_features = model.encode_text(text)
                #print(text_features.shape)
                
                # Getting Image and Text Embeddings (with same dimension)
                #print(image_features.shape)
                #print(image_projection.projection.weight.shape)
                image_embeddings = image_projection(image_features)
                text_embeddings = text_projection(text_features)
                
                logits = (text_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T)
                images_similarity = image_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T
                texts_similarity = text_embeddings @ text_embeddings.T
                targets = F.softmax(
                    (images_similarity + texts_similarity) / 2, dim=-1
                )
                
                n_train += images.size(0)

                texts_loss = cross_entropy(logits, targets, reduction='none')
                images_loss = cross_entropy(logits.T, targets.T, reduction='none')
                loss =  (images_loss + texts_loss) / 2.0 # shape: (batch_size)
                total_loss += loss * images.size(0)
                
                loss = loss.mean()
                # Backward pass and optimize
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                                
            total_loss = (total_loss / n_train) * 100
            wandb.log({ "train_loss_per_epoch": total_loss})
            
            
            # VALIDATION LOOP
            model.eval()
            val_loss = 0
            n_val = 0
            top1_val, total_loss_val, n_val,top5_val = 0., 0., 0.,0.
            for i, batch in enumerate(val_dataloader):
                images = batch['image'].cuda()
                text = batch['target']
                
                if isinstance(text, str):
                    text = torch.tensor(text).cuda()
                else:
                    text = text.cuda() #to cuda only tensors
                                    
                # Zero the gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                image_features = model.encode_image(images)
                text = text.squeeze(1)  # Remove the extra dimension
                text_features = model.encode_text(text)

                # Getting Image and Text Embeddings (with same dimension)
                image_embeddings = image_projection(image_features)
                text_embeddings = text_projection(text_features)

                logits = (text_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T)
                images_similarity = image_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T
                texts_similarity = text_embeddings @ text_embeddings.T
                targets = F.softmax(
                    (images_similarity + texts_similarity) / 2, dim=-1
                )
    
                n_val += images.size(0)

                texts_loss = cross_entropy(logits, targets, reduction='none')
                images_loss = cross_entropy(logits.T, targets.T, reduction='none')
                loss =  (images_loss + texts_loss) / 2.0 # shape: (batch_size)
                loss.requires_grad = True
                val_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
                
            val_loss = (val_loss / n_val)*100
            val_losses.append(val_loss)
            wandb.log({"val_loss_per_epoch": val_loss})
            
    
            # Overfitting detection
            if epoch > 1 and val_losses[-1] > val_losses[-2] and train_losses[-1] < train_losses[-2]:
                increasing_val_loss_counter += 1
                if increasing_val_loss_counter >= patience:
                    print("Overfitting detected. Training loss is decreasing but validation loss is increasing.")
                    break
            else:
                increasing_val_loss_counter = 0
            # Early stopping
            if val_loss < best_val_loss:
                best_val_loss = val_loss
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_weights.pth')
            else:
                print("Early stopping due to validation loss not decreasing")
                break
            scheduler.step()
        # Save the model
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_weights.pth')

    #TEST LOOP
    # Load the saved model weights
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_weights.pth'))

    # Put the model in evaluation mode
    model.eval()

    # Initialize the test loss
    test_losses = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    # No need to track gradients in test mode
    with torch.no_grad():
        top1_test, test_loss, n_test,top5_test = 0., 0., 0.,0.
        for i, batch in enumerate(tqdm(test_dataloader)):
            images = batch['image'].cuda()
            text = batch['target']
            
            if isinstance(text, str):
                text = torch.tensor(text).cuda()
            else:
                text = text.cuda() #to cuda only tensors
                                
            # Zero the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            image_features = model.encode_image(images)
            text = text.squeeze(1)  # Remove the extra dimension
            text_features = model.encode_text(text)
            # Getting Image and Text Embeddings (with same dimension)
            image_embeddings = image_projection(image_features)
            text_embeddings = text_projection(text_features)

            logits = (text_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T)
            images_similarity = image_embeddings @ image_embeddings.T
            texts_similarity = text_embeddings @ text_embeddings.T
            targets= F.softmax(
                (images_similarity + texts_similarity) / 2, dim=-1
            )
            
            n_test += images.size(0)

            texts_loss = cross_entropy(logits, targets, reduction='none')
            images_loss = cross_entropy(logits.T, targets.T, reduction='none')
            loss =  (images_loss + texts_loss) / 2.0 # shape: (batch_size)
            loss.requires_grad = True
            test_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)

        test_loss = (test_loss / n_test)*100
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        wandb.log({"test_loss_per_epoch": test_loss})
        
    wandb.finish()

